remix vite:build works fine on macOS, stalls at ✓ 1311 modules transformed. when moving to linux server
My remix app was using classic build, I've migrated to vite, and all is fine on my macOS development machine. When moving to the Linux server, I do
remix Vite:build and it stalls at
"✓ 1311 modules transformed."
Then it hangs. Looking at processes, node is having 20/25% CPU constantly, and never ends (waited 2 minutes...)
Any advice?

I've found it works in my home folder /home/myuser/myproject, the problem is somehow at /var/www/website/web-site where server code is built and run....

Ii've found it!
The folder ./public/uploads with many many files, are being copied by vite to ./build/client which is not what I need.
My solution was to move those files to ./uploads and refactor my upload handling code. Cheers!
